# Handling RSA keys Node.JS within variables

Tags: node.js, variables, openssl, rsa

I'm creating a server that has a function to transmit a public key via a post request so the client can encrypt data with this key and post back with the encrypted data.

My overall question here, is **how can I transmit an RSA public key within a variable while maintaining line breaks**.

I have considered manually adding \n (newline) characters however, I can't figure out a way to do this programmatically after a key is generated with openssl.

Specifically, here are some issues I run into.

```
var newkey = " -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHikastc8+I81zCg/qWW8dMr8m
qvXQ3qbPAmu0RjxoZVI47tvskYlFAXOf0sPrhO2nUuooJngnHV0639iTTEYG1vck
NaW2R6U5QTdQ5Rq5u+uV3pMk7w7Vs4n3urQ6jnqt2rTXbC1DNa/PFeAZatbf7ffB
By0IGO0zc128IshYcwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY----- ";
```

*(obviously) this won't work because node only recognizes the first line within the quotations and attempts to parse the second line as code, throwing an error*

```
 '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I have also attempted concatenating the RSA key into one line, unfortunately openSSL doesn't like this and spits out an error.

Do you have a better idea on how I can handle RSA keys within a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: May sound obvious, but have you tried using template literals ( Strings delimited by ` instead of " or ' ) ? They do support line breaks, as opposed to "typical" strings.

Comment: Can you formulate this into an answer so I can give you an upvote, I should have remembered this sooner.

Comment: Done. Glad to have solved your problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May sound obvious, but have you tried using template literals (strings delimited by ` instead of " or ')? They do support line breaks, as opposed to "typical" strings.